# Change default directory of posh-git windows

Tags: git, powershell

How do I change the start up directory of posh-git? No matter what I do it doesn't change.

Comment: Posh-Git is a powershell module. What do you mean by "start up directory of posh-git" ? Do you mean the directory powershell starts in ?

Comment: Yes. Although I have tried changing the start directory of powershell but it doesn't change it when open posh-git.

Comment: Can you give more information on how you open powershell, what directory you want to start in, and what directory it opens in instead ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open PowerShell from a shortcut, there is a "Start In" property :
[image]

If you open PowerShell from a better console emulator such as [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki) or [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), there should be similar configuration option :
[image]

If none of the above works for you, you could try to change your powershell profile (or create one) in `~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` and adding a command there to change directory

```
cd c:/starting/directory/
```

Comment: I have tried the first method but it doesn't work and I am unsure about creating profiles.

Comment: Since you use posh-git, there should already be a profile file created for you. You just have to append the `cd` command at the end of it.

Comment: What did you put in the "Start in" property ? Maybe there is an error in it, or maybe you don't have the rights on this folder

Comment: It should be in `C:\Users\<your user name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`. You can also find this path information in the `$profile` variable

Comment: WindowsPowerShell isn't in my documents folder.

Comment: How did you install posh-git ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110503/discussion-between-guillaume-collic-and-fungie).

Comment: With github I think.

Comment: You can create the powershell profile with this command (change the `c:/starting/directory` to the folder you want to open Powershell in) : `mkdir ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($profile));"cd c:/starting/directory" >> $profile`

Comment: If you don't have a profile yet, then [posh-git](http://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/) is not correctly configured